# Archieve a Header and "Sub-Header" with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am failing to correctly organize jQuery Mobile components in the following way:

[image: Modified Screenshot]

I was trying to build this fixed searchbar, but after many attemps I ended up here, asking for help.

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <a data-role="button" class="ui-btn-lft" href="#pgIndex" data-icon="arrow-l" data-theme="b">Back</a>
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" id="second-header">
        <div style="float:left; width: 75%;">
            <select name="selCombo1" id="selCombo1" data-mini="true">
                <option value="0">Option 0 - All</option>
            </select>
            <span style="margin-bottom: 3px;"></span>
            <select name="selCombo2" id="selCombo2" data-mini="true">
                <option value="0">Option 0 - All</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right; width: 25%;">
            <a data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="top" data-rel="back">Search</a>     
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there a simple way to archieve this?

The complete code is on jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mbarni/rjdt2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve a similar effect to a second header level by appending a div with the classes:

```
class="ui-bar ui-bar-b"
```

to your header. Here's a simple example using your code.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rjdt2/10/)

[For more info, check the bottom of this doc](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer!